# Redis server console output clarification?

Tags: redis

I'm looking at the redis output console and I'm trying to understand the displayed info : 
*(didn't find that info in the [quick guide](http://redis.io/topics/quickstart))*

So `redis-server.exe` outputs this :

```
/*1*/   [2476] 24 Apr 11:46:28 # Open data file dump.rdb: No such file or directory
/*2*/   [2476] 24 Apr 11:46:28 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
/*3*/   [2476] 24 Apr 11:42:35 - 1 clients connected (0 slaves), 1188312 bytes in use
/*4*/   [2476] 24 Apr 11:42:40 - DB 0: 1 keys (0 volatile) in 4 slots HT.
```

- Regarding line `#1` - what does the dump.rdb file is used for ? is it the data itself ?
- what is the `[2476]` number ? it is not a port since line `#2` tells port is `6379`
- What does `(0 slaves)` means ?
- in line #3 - `1188312` bytes used - but  what is the max value so i'd know overflows ...? is it for whole databases ?
- Line `#3` What does  `(0 volatile)`  means ?
- Line `#4` - why do i have 4 slots HT ? I have no data yet

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`[2476]` - process ID

`dump.rdb` - redis can persist data by snapshoting, dump.rdb is the default file name http://redis.io/topics/persistence

`0 slaves` - redis can work in master-slave mode, `0 slaves` informs you that there are no slave servers connected

`1188312 bytes in use` - total number of bytes allocated by Redis using its allocator

`0 volatile` - redis can set keys with expiration time, this is the count of them

`4 slots HT` - current hash table size, initial table size is 4, as you add more items hash table will grow

Comment: Tnx , regarding hash size  -- idont have any . So why the size ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir it's allocated hash table size, it will grow as you will be adding new keys